# Is there a way to disable tab key action?

Tags: javascript, html

I am designing a single page website with some forms. It has 3 divs in it, 2 of them off the screen and i am using `overflow:hidden` to hide them from users. But when tab key pressed browsers scrolls to the next div with a broken design.

So, is there a way to disable tab key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving elements off-screen is a terrible way of hiding them. `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` are there for a reason, and that reason is not "to be replaced with `left: -9999px`.

Comment: yes i know, but for animations i need to put them there at some point

Comment: erm... why? I've done all kinds of animations and many of them start from `display: none`. Moving elements off-screen to slide them on is okay, but I use `position:fixed` so they don't affect scrolling the page, etc. etc. etc.. I don't see any reason to ever have positioning to "hide" an element in this way.

Comment: i'm a little intoxicated i guess, i really forgot about fixed positioning today :D you're right sorry

Answer (score 2):

Set property `tabindex=-1` for an element and it will not be keyboard focusable.